# Stop the hate, it's unfair

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> First or second, I don't care.
>   I'm usually hated, people despair.
>   For some, my name sounds like a blare
>   but I can bring happiness, I swear.

Hint (if you are stuck):

> My name was a gift, so debonair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be

> Monday !

Because :
First or second, I don't care

> Monday can be the first day of the week or the second (side note : I discovered that on wristwatches, and monday being the second day is something I can't wrap my head around)

I'm usually hated, people despair

> "How is it going ?" "Like a monday !"

For some, my name, sound like a blare

> I don't get this one ! :D **EDIT :** Perhaps unhappy peoples screaming ?

Lastly,  but I can bring happyness, I swear

> because, uh..., if you consider it being the first day of the week, something nice can happen in this new week ?

As a comment, if and only if my answer is right, the hint might be a bit too obvious !

Comment: it is correct! hahah if i dont put the hint i think is too dificult.. with it too easy ... is your pick to reveal it. about the blare, is regarding also the hate

Comment: im  struggling today, after vacation ... and i thought about this riddle lol the part about happiness is because is not always bad

Comment: It would be quite hard without it, that's right ! Maybe making it less obvious by removing the name of the celestial body ?

Comment: like. "my name was a gift, so debonair"?

Comment: I'm not good at poetry, especially when I do it quickly, but something like "The daughter of titans gave me my name, so debonair", because [Selene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selene) is the daughter of Hyperion and Theia and is the goddess of the moon ?

Comment: well, .. a bit long i think. im also not a poet, not even a native english speaker hehe thanks for helping and congrats for solving !

Comment: Monday is usually the start of a payroll period and workweek, which is why some calendars have the option to select it.